# google Cloud Messaging Push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Can I use POSTMAN client on Google Chrome to send payload message to GCM server for testing purpose.
Secondly if yes, what is the header and url parameter to be sent.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you can.

### 1. Send a notification with a JSON payload

URL: `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`

Headers:

- Authorization: key=<your-api-key>
- Content-Type: application/json

Body (click on the 'raw' tab):

```
{
  "collapse_key": "score_update",
  "time_to_live": 108,
  "delay_while_idle": true,
  "data": {
    "score": "4x8",
    "time": "15:16.2342"
  },
  "registration_ids":["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```

Note: `registration_ids` is the only required field, all the others are optional.

### 2. Send a notification with a plain text payload

URL: `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`

Headers:

- Authorization: key=<your-api-key>
- Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8

Body (click on the 'x-www-form-urlencoded' tab):

```
collapse_key=score_update
time_to_live=108
delay_while_idle=1
data.score=4x8
data.time=15:16.2342
registration_id=42
```

Note: `registration_id` is the only required field, all the others are optional.

---

Source: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html

Comment: Nice one! I just wasted 2 hours trying to figure out why your answer wasn't working for me (401 Unauthorized error) before I realised that the Authorization header needs to have value `key=ABC...`, and not just `ABC...` Maybe that helps someone else - works a charm now.

Comment: Hi.. i tested using json and form format for payload.. i receive the push notification but always my event.data is null  , any ideas how to pass the data?

Comment: The time_to_live parameter here is set to 108 seconds only, it is a bit low I believe.

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record and to complete the nice answer from @Alexandru Rosianu the GCM endpoint changed a while ago and it is suggested to use the new one. Here is an example taken from the official docs:

### Authentication

To send a message, the application server issues a POST request. For example:

```
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

A message request is made of 2 parts: HTTP header and HTTP body.

The HTTP header must contain the following headers:

- `Authorization`: key=YOUR_API_KEY
- `Content-Type`: `application/json` for JSON; `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8` for plain text. If `Content-Type` is omitted, the format is assumed to be plain text.

For example:

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=YOUR_API_KEY

{
  "notification": {
      "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "text": "5 to 1"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_H..."
}
```

The HTTP body content depends on whether you're using JSON or plain text. See [the Server Reference](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#params) for a list of all the parameters your JSON or plain text message can contain.

**Example using Curl:**

```
# curl --header "Authorization: key=YOUR_API_KEY" \
       --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
       https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send \
       -d "{\"notification\": { \"title\": \"Portugal vs. Denmark\"," \
          "\"text\": \"5 to 1\" }, \"to\" : \"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_H...\" }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use POSTMAN.

This GCM Notification Test Tool simplifies the server side testing immensely by reducing the number of items you enter in POSTMAN everytime - http://techzog.com/development/gcm-notification-test-tool-android/