# Push Notifications in android app receiver, Sender Web Service

Tags: android, asp.net, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying an example app for push notification in android app only receiving.

I have  a Broacast Receiver and a Service:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService
```

I got the regId using below Code:

```
regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
```

**1. How can I validate regID received is okay or not ?**

**2. is this is enough from my app to receive notifications? I'm asking this because most of the example I've seen implemented Sender in android app**

**3. I have already a Broadcast Receiver why I need a Service?**

**4. I'm planning to implement a Web Server which can communicate with GCM. For this my app needs to sent redId to Web server. I understand web service needs 
*REGISTRATION ID, API Key, Message Text to send to GCM*. Whats the the format JSON? if yes whats the URL and method type GET or POST. or any example in ASP .net**

**5. Is there any open software, where I can test my app notification receiver behavior without implementing server on my own ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I try to answer
1) If gcm can't register, you can see on logcat. 
2) I didn't understand.
3) BroadcastReceiver isn't wakefull. Also if you want a background task you can't do it. So you can use WakefulBroadcastReceiver and startWakefullService. So you can what do you want to. 
4) You can get more information there https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/
5) I found it https://github.com/uniqush, but ı didn't try. If you haven't enough time, you can use Parse :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. regarding my 2nd question all examples I have seen having Sending regId and user information to web server? is that means all devices send this?  why we need to do that? is regId different for all users ?

Comment: Yes all the devices must send regid to your server, Because Google GCM servers recognize device with regid.

Comment: But Push Notifications are sent to all app users, then why we need to do this? A single regId form a device should be enough right ?

Answer (score 1):

1) A valid GCM registration id starts with "APA..". So print it and check this value;

2) The old documentation suggested a class called *GcmManager* to deal with the device registration and it was something like this:

```
public class GcmManager {

    private static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private static final String TAG = GcmManager.class.getSimpleName();
    private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    private Context mContext;

    public GcmManager(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public void registerIfNeeded() {
        final String regId = getRegistrationId();
        Log.d(TAG, "regId: " + regId);
        if (regId.isEmpty()) {
            registerInBackground();
        }
        else {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend(regId);
                }
            }).run();
        }
    }

    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGcmPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public String getRegistrationId() {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGcmPreferences(mContext);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }

        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(mContext);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }

    private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(mContext);
                    }
                    String regId = gcm.register(Constants.GCM_SENDER_ID);
                    storeRegistrationId(mContext, regId);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                final String regId = getRegistrationId();
                if (!regId.isEmpty()) {
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend(regId);
                }
            }

        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }

    private SharedPreferences getGcmPreferences(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(GcmManager.class.getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend(String regId) {
        // Send registration Id to your API
    }
}
```

Then you should call the method `registerIfNeeded` to check if the device is already registered, as the name suggests;

3) The official documentation of [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) states:

> Helper for the common pattern of implementing a BroadcastReceiver that receives a device wakeup event and then passes the work off to a Service, while ensuring that the device does not go back to sleep during the transition.

4 and 5) [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27874454/3280779) shows how to easily do a request directly to GCM using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). This is a good approach for testing and you can use the request as an example for your own API

Comment: Thanks for the answers, If app is installed on 10 users phone, do all users send regId to Server? I tried with one user regId to Send Push notifications, I did received notification But  is that means only one user will receive it ? why do we need to send all users regId to Server? In that case how can I send push notification for all app users? Is there any other way ?

Comment: This architecture provides a message from the server to ONE device referenced by the unique identifier. However Google Cloud Messaging has evolved and there are a documentation on this subject https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications