# Can I test whether notification appeared using UI test?

Tags: android, ui-testing

I created UI test for my application, but now, I can´t find the possibility to check if notification appeared and then push it using UI tests.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: You can test your notification using Google chrome extension called Postman refer this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27874454/2713414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite difficult to test notification on UI test.
Run the app on any compatible android device to test notifications.

You can also try this.

Implement Google Cloud Messaging in your app.

“Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that helps developers send data from servers to their Android applications on Android devices”.
 Using this service you can send data to your application whenever new data is available instead of making requests to server in timely fashion. Integrating GCM in your android application enhances user experience and saves lot of battery power. 
--https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: thanks for the answer. It is not exactly what I need, but also very useful service